# Django hideously slow with 8000 model instances (How to drop PostgreSQL database)?

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql

I have a Django installation running on the development server. I recently used `python manage.py loaddata 8000models.json`. Now everything is super slow. Pages won't load. `python manage.py flush` does not return. `ModelType.objects.count()` does not return.

(Or maybe they will return if I wait a sufficiently long time.)

What's going on here? Is Django truly unable to handle that much data? Or is there some other issue?

**Update**: I observe this issue on PostgreSQL but not SQLite with the same amount of data. Perhaps I just need to wipe the PostgreSQL and reload the data.

**Update 2**: How can I wipe the PostgreSQL and reset? `python manage.py reset appname` isn't responding.

**Update 3**: This is how I'm trying to wipe the PostgreSQL:

```
#! bin/bash

sudo -u postgres dropdb mydb
sudo -u postgres createdb mydb
sudo -u postgres psql mydb < ~/my-setup/my-init.sql
python ~/path/to/manage.py syncdb
```

However, this causes the following errors:

```
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  database "mydb" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 8 other session(s) using the database.
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  database "mydb" already exists
ERROR:  role "myrole" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  owner of table mydb.mytable_mytable
# ... more "owner of table", "owner of sequence" statements, etc
```

How can I close out these other sessions? I don't have Apache running. I've only been using one instance of the Django development server at a time. However, when it got unresponsive I killed it with Control+Z. Perhaps that caused it to not release a database connection, thereby causing this issue? How can I get around this?

Comment: What DB back end are you using?

Comment: Use either "PostgreSQL" and "SQLite" or "PostGre" and "ite".

Comment: What, exactly, does `loaddata 8000models.json` load?

Comment: 800 model instances I guess. So he's inserting 800 object in the db and things slow down. Maybe your network is broken.

Comment: @Ubersoldat right, except it works fine with SQLite.

Comment: You can't drop the DB as it's being used. Stop apache/lig before dropping the database.

Comment: If you're loading testbed data with json, you might consider trying to store your testbed data in a postgresql template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl-Z just stops the process, it does not kill it. (I assume you're using bash) type `jobs` in your terminal, and you should see the old processes still running.

Once you kill all the jobs that are accessing the PostgreSQL database, you should be able to drop, create, and syncdb as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking that your postrgres database is still replying at all, from the sounds of it it is probably processing the data you told it to load.

When loading the data you should just let it finish first. If pages are still taking a very long time to render you should check your queries instead.

Using .count(), even in PostgreSQL (which has rather slow counts) with 8000 items should return within a good amount of time.